# How can I conditionally only log something if it's a certain Class?

Tags: python, django

Something like this:

```
if self.__class__ == "User":
                logging.debug("%s non_pks were found" %  (str(len(non_pks))) )

In [2]: user = User.objects.get(pk=1)

In [3]: user.__class__
Out[3]: <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>

In [4]: if user.__class__ == 'django.contrib.auth.models.User': print "yes"
   ...: 

In [5]: user.__class__ == 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'
Out[5]: False

In [6]: user.__class__ == 'User'
Out[6]: False

In [7]: user.__class__ == "<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>"
Out[7]: False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes are first class objects in Python:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.__class__ == Foo
True
```

Note: they're not strings, they're objects. Don't compare to `"Foo"` but to `Foo`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
if user.__class__.__name__ == 'User':
```

Comment: Why are you checking the name of the class, rather than comparing the class objects themselves? (This works even in the face of same-named classes in different modules, for example)

Comment: Your method is better indeed, I was looking for strings because he actually compared with them (upvoted yours).